# How can we relate different controls such as check box, drop down list etc with the chart conrol in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can we relate different controls such as check box, drop down list, etc with the chart control in ASP.Net MVC?

We can't use postback method in ASP.Net MVC then how can we perform different events in ASP.Net MVC on helpers?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery can help here. You can hook up JQuery to asynchronously call a controller action when for example a checkbox is checked or a dropdownlist changes. The action could then regenerate the chart and return it as the actionresult.

Here's a basic example of the controller action:

http://www.myblogon.net/archive/2009/02/15/21.aspx